# Androidstudio Problem with view adding and removing

Tags: java, android-studio

I started AStudio 5 days ago and I'm currently trying to make a CardView swipe system, and I wanted it to be infinite. So, there is two card 1 and 2, 1 is over 2, and when 1 was slided I remove it, and add 3 behind 2.

```java
    private void regenCard(View v) {
        View cardToShow = (View)cardList.get((counter+2)%cardList.size());
        cardToShow.setTranslationZ(400000-counter);
        myLayout.removeViewAt(2);
        myLayout.addView(cardToShow,3);
        counter++;
    }
```

Note: the first two card are initialized in MainActivity (I know this is not beautiful)
I was hoping that by removing 1 (which was at index 2) 2 would go to index 2 so I could add 3 after them. The structure of the MainActivity is like this:

Relative Layout

```
    0. ImageView
    1. Relative Layout
    2. Card 1
    3. Card 2
```

But when I run the app, I can only swipe one card, the second one makes me crash

```java
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.regenCard(MyOnTouchListener.java:133)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.next(MyOnTouchListener.java:120)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.onTouch(MyOnTouchListener.java:76)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14305)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3112)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2785)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3140)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.isparks.project, PID: 17652
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.regenCard(MyOnTouchListener.java:133)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.next(MyOnTouchListener.java:120)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.onTouch(MyOnTouchListener.java:76)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14305)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3112)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2785)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3140)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17652 SIG: 9E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.regenCard(MyOnTouchListener.java:133)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.next(MyOnTouchListener.java:120)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.onTouch(MyOnTouchListener.java:76)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14305)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3112)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2785)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3140)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.isparks.project, PID: 17652
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.regenCard(MyOnTouchListener.java:133)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.next(MyOnTouchListener.java:120)
        at com.isparks.project.MyOnTouchListener.onTouch(MyOnTouchListener.java:76)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14305)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3112)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2785)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3140)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17652 SIG: 9
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error, it's required to call `removeView()`.

In your code, before calling "`myLayout.addView`", add the following line

```
if(cardToShow.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewGroup)cardToShow.getParent()).removeView(cardToShow); 
}
```

Comment: After some edits it worked, thank you a lot